# Rendering jQuery autocomplete items as inline block

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to display a functional set of results (e.g. be able to use arrow keys to select) using jQuery autocomplete but instead of the results displaying in a normal list I want them to display as an `inline-block`.

Here is the code I have.

```
$( "#people_q" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: projects,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#people_q" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#people_q" ).val( ui.item.label );
            $( "#people_q-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
            $( "#people_q-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
            $( "#people_q-icon" ).attr( "src", "images/" + ui.item.icon );

            return false;
        }
    })
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
});
```

Here is the styling I tried.

```
<style>
    .ui-autocomplete {
    width:600px !important;
}

    .ui-menu-item {
        width:200px !important;
        display:inline !important;  
        }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UL` width gets set inline within the autocomplete script which outranks your css rules. You can over ride like this:

```
$(selector).data("autocomplete")._resizeMenu=function() {
      /* do nothing and will be width of page*/
       $.noop();
      /* OR set width */
     var ul = this.menu.element;
      $(ul).width(600);
};
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/M92kX/2/